# LEFT JOIN not working as intended

Tags: mysql, index, join, foreign-key, mysql-8.0

I'm using mysql 8.0.21. I'm trying to join two tables such that I can find the index name of foreign keys. This is my query:

```
SELECT KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
    STATISTICS.INDEX_NAME  
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
LEFT JOIN information_schema.STATISTICS 
ON STATISTICS.TABLE_NAME = KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME 
    AND STATISTICS.COLUMN_NAME = KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME 
WHERE KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME <> 'PRIMARY'
    AND KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA IS NOT NULL
    AND KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('mysql','performance_schema','sys')
    AND STATISTICS.INDEX_NAME <> 'PRIMARY';
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------------+------------+
| CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | TABLE_SCHEMA      | REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME   | INDEX_NAME |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------------+------------+
| StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance       | ATTENDANCE | STUDENT               | RollNumber  | RollNumber             | ATTENDANCE_ibfk_1 | RollNumber |
| StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance       | STUDENT    | GUARDIAN              | GUID        | GUID                   | STUDENT_ibfk_1    | GUID       |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | branch     | employee              | mgr_id      | emp_id                 | branch_ibfk_1     | mgr_id     |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | employee   | branch                | branch_id   | branch_id              | employee_ibfk_1   | branch_id  |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | employee   | employee              | super_id    | emp_id                 | employee_ibfk_2   | super_id   |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | client     | branch                | branch_id   | branch_id              | client_ibfk_1     | branch_id  |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | works_with | client                | client_id   | client_id              | works_with_ibfk_2 | client_id  |
| OFFICE            | OFFICE            | OFFICE                  | EMPLOYEE   | DEPARTMENT            | DeptId      | DeptId                 | EMPLOYEE_ibfk_1   | DeptId     |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

But the output that I'm expecting is not this. I'll explain my situation.

---

The query I used for finding all the foreign keys is this:

```
SELECT KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, 
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME <> 'PRIMARY'
    AND KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA IS NOT NULL
    AND KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('mysql','performance_schema','sys')
ORDER BY KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME ASC,
    KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME ASC;
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | TABLE_SCHEMA      | REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME      | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME        |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance       | ATTENDANCE      | STUDENT               | RollNumber  | RollNumber             | ATTENDANCE_ibfk_1      |
| OFFICE            | OFFICE            | OFFICE                  | EMPLOYEE        | DEPARTMENT            | DeptId      | DeptId                 | EMPLOYEE_ibfk_1        |
| StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance       | STUDENT         | GUARDIAN              | GUID        | GUID                   | STUDENT_ibfk_1         |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | branch          | employee              | mgr_id      | emp_id                 | branch_ibfk_1          |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | branch_supplier | branch                | branch_id   | branch_id              | branch_supplier_ibfk_1 |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | client          | branch                | branch_id   | branch_id              | client_ibfk_1          |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | employee        | branch                | branch_id   | branch_id              | employee_ibfk_1        |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | employee        | employee              | super_id    | emp_id                 | employee_ibfk_2        |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | works_with      | client                | client_id   | client_id              | works_with_ibfk_2      |
| technastic        | technastic        | technastic              | works_with      | employee              | emp_id      | emp_id                 | works_with_ibfk_1      |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I also checked if the output displayed all the foreign keys by checking it with another query:

`select * from referential_constraints;`

Output:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME        | UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME | MATCH_OPTION | UPDATE_RULE | DELETE_RULE | TABLE_NAME      | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME |
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| def                | StudentAttendance | ATTENDANCE_ibfk_1      | def                       | StudentAttendance        | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | NO ACTION   | ATTENDANCE      | STUDENT               |
| def                | StudentAttendance | STUDENT_ibfk_1         | def                       | StudentAttendance        | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | NO ACTION   | STUDENT         | GUARDIAN              |
| def                | technastic        | branch_ibfk_1          | def                       | technastic               | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | SET NULL    | branch          | employee              |
| def                | technastic        | employee_ibfk_1        | def                       | technastic               | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | SET NULL    | employee        | branch                |
| def                | technastic        | employee_ibfk_2        | def                       | technastic               | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | SET NULL    | employee        | employee              |
| def                | technastic        | client_ibfk_1          | def                       | technastic               | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | SET NULL    | client          | branch                |
| def                | technastic        | works_with_ibfk_1      | def                       | technastic               | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | CASCADE     | works_with      | employee              |
| def                | technastic        | works_with_ibfk_2      | def                       | technastic               | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | CASCADE     | works_with      | client                |
| def                | technastic        | branch_supplier_ibfk_1 | def                       | technastic               | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | CASCADE     | branch_supplier | branch                |
| def                | OFFICE            | EMPLOYEE_ibfk_1        | def                       | OFFICE                   | PRIMARY                | NONE         | NO ACTION   | NO ACTION   | EMPLOYEE        | DEPARTMENT            |
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Since all the constraint names which were in `referential_constraints` table are also there in `key_column_usage` table, we can go ahead.

---

Now I wanted to find the index names of all the foreign keys. Since there was no perfect query to find the index names of all foreign keys, I came up with this query:

```
SELECT STATISTICS.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    STATISTICS.INDEX_SCHEMA, 
    STATISTICS.TABLE_NAME, 
    STATISTICS.COLUMN_NAME, 
    STATISTICS.INDEX_NAME
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS 
WHERE STATISTICS.INDEX_NAME <> 'PRIMARY' 
    AND STATISTICS.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('mysql','performance_schema','sys')
ORDER BY STATISTICS.TABLE_NAME ASC,
    STATISTICS.COLUMN_NAME ASC;
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA      | INDEX_SCHEMA      | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | INDEX_NAME |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance | ATTENDANCE | RollNumber  | RollNumber |
| OFFICE            | OFFICE            | EMPLOYEE   | DeptId      | DeptId     |
| StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance | GUARDIAN   | GPhone      | GPhone     |
| StudentAttendance | StudentAttendance | STUDENT    | GUID        | GUID       |
| technastic        | technastic        | branch     | mgr_id      | mgr_id     |
| technastic        | technastic        | client     | branch_id   | branch_id  |
| technastic        | technastic        | employee   | branch_id   | branch_id  |
| technastic        | technastic        | employee   | super_id    | super_id   |
| technastic        | technastic        | works_with | client_id   | client_id  |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The problem with this query is that it doesn't find index names **only** for foreign keys. In the output, the column *GPhone* is not a foreign key; it's a unique key.

---

Now I wanted to join these two tables (LEFT OUTER JOIN to be specific) to easily identify the index names of the respective foreign keys. The output that I expected was this:
[image: output that I expected]

Please let me know where did I go wrong and what is the correct query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic SQL Gotcha!

```
  "LEFT JOIN" + WHERE condition(s) on "right" table => "INNER JOIN"
```

Restructure your query so that the conditions on the "right" table go into a *join* clause, not the *where* clause:

```
SELECT 
  . . . 
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE  kcu
LEFT JOIN information_schema.STATISTICS   s 
       ON s.TABLE_NAME = kcu.TABLE_NAME 
      AND s.COLUMN_NAME = kcu.COLUMN_NAME 
      AND s.INDEX_NAME <> 'PRIMARY'               <-- Condition on "right" table 
WHERE 
    kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME <> 'PRIMARY'
AND kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'NULL'         <-- 'NULL' or NULL ?  BIG difference. 
AND kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ( 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'sys' )
ORDER BY 
  . . . 
;
```

Comment: Is my query the only way to find index names of foreign keys or is there any other better query?

Comment: If I don't use single quotes for `NULL`, the output is `Empty set (0.00 sec)` .

Comment: @technatic_tc, NULL is not equal to anything, not even NULL. Use  `kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA  IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Your query worked @Lennart. I'll edit the question and answer now.

Answer (score 0):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS contains only foreign keys, so by joining with that you rule out other types of constraints:

```
select s.table_schema
     , s.table_name
     , kcu.constraint_name
     , s.index_schema
     , s.index_name
     , s.column_name 
from information_schema.referential_constraints rc
join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
    on rc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = kcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    and rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    and rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
join information_schema.STATISTICS s
    on s.TABLE_SCHEMA = kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA
    and s.TABLE_NAME = kcu.TABLE_NAME
    and s.COLUMN_NAME = kcu.COLUMN_NAME
order by s.table_schema, s.table_name, kcu.constraint_name, s.seq_in_index
;
```

Note that this query returns columns for indexes not necesarly related to the foreign key. In for example:

```
create table p1 (a int not null, b int not null,  primary key(a,b));
create table c1 (a int not null, b int not null, c int not null, primary key (a,b,c)); 
alter table c1 add constraint fk1 foreign key (a,b) references p1 (a,b);
```

the columns for the primary key are returned because the fk can use them. You can experiment with this [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5093f328183996686dc7a5869b97887) if that is not what is intended.

EDIT:

The premise for the query is a bit unclear. I'll try to illustrate that with the following [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5b5682ab61e075de1541e7541b9291e)

If we create tables like:

```
create table p1 (a int not null, b int not null,  primary key(a,b));
create table c1 (a int not null, b int not null, c int not null, primary key (a,b,c));
alter table c1 add constraint fk1 foreign key (a,b) references p1 (a,b);
```

An index is created for the primary key, but not for the foreign key, because that would be redundant.

```
select index_name, column_name 
from information_schema.statistics 
where table_name = 'c1';

PRIMARY a
PRIMARY b
PRIMARY c
```

If we, on the other hand, create a new table c2 without the primary key:

```
create table c2 (a int not null, b int not null, c int not null); 
alter table c2 add constraint fk2 foreign key (a,b) references p1 (a,b);
```

MySQL automatically creates an index for this foreign key (not all DBMS do this)

```
select index_name, column_name 
from information_schema.statistics 
where table_name = 'c2';

fk2 a
fk2 b
```

What would you like reported in the case of tables c1 and c2?

I guess my point is that a foreign key is a logical concept (described in SQL standard), whereas an index is a physical concept. There is no one-one correspondence between a foreign key and an index.

Comment: I'm very new to `JOIN`. Joining three tables seems complex for me. I actually need index names *only* of foreign keys. In case if you can modify the query accordingly, please do so.

Comment: Well, a foreign key may or may not use an index, but the index does not belong to the foreign key. In my test case above, it would be stupid to create an index on c1 (a,b) because the primary key index c1(a, b, c) already covers that. What problem are you trying to solve? Finding foreign keys that does not have an index that supports the foreign key for referential integrity ?

Comment: I was actually trying to find an answer for this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/271312/213118

Comment: The question is in a sense impossible to answer. I'll update my answer with an explanation